# Allied Vision ALVIUM USB can not detected

Tags: python, opencv, flir, alliedvision

I have connected 1 "Allied vision Alvium USB" cam, 1 "Allied vision Mako GIGE" cam and 5 "Flir GIGE" cam with Jetson AGX. When I run only Allied vision cam's image grabbing python script then it works properly, both USB and GIGE cam image's are grabbing. But when run Flir cam script in parallel that time Allied vision USB cam didn't detected and not display in the cam list or sdk. After unplugged and re-plug USB cable, USB cam display in cam list and in sdk.
I tried to run all cam sequentially then also I got same issue. I tried by reducing the number of flir cams then also issue not solved.
I don't understand how to run all cam's at a time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have found the Alvium USB camera to be sensitive to amount of power provided over the USB 3.1 interface.  Does the green power LED at the back of the camera illuminate? If not it means the camera is not able to draw enough power over USB.  It typically draws 1.7W at 5V.  You could try supplying 5V DC via the J-7 GPIO connector, not sure which pins you need to use.  If the green power LED is still lit but camera is not detected then you have a different issue that I have no suggestions for resolving.

Comment: @gb96's point may explain some issues I'm having, and may or may not be related to the fact it works reliably on some USB3 ports on my test system, but not on others (the front panel ones are intermittent)

Comment: Also encountered intermittent success on some USB3 ports as per @ChrisH comment, green light on and cam detected but errors attempting to start streaming video. Shorter and/or more shielded USB cables can resolve the problem. Might be EMI. With some problematic USB cables I could influence the test result by changing the direction or route of the cable between computer and camera.